# Python: Parse log file for pairs of lines

Tags: python, parsing

I have a log file that I need to parse for specific events. The problem is the data I need comes from pairs of event entries that each hold pieces of the data needed.

For instance there will be a line with an event type = test with some data and then shortly after there is another line with an event type = test2 with some more data.

There may be many instances of these pairs of data in the file or none.

What I need to do is tell the code that when it finds a line with event=test then also look for the next instance of event=test2 which is usually a couple of lines later in the log.

This is a sample of the data file:

```
2020-08-25 03:36:56.006 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1600.0064477}
2020-08-25 03:37:01.006 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1605.0066958}
2020-08-25 03:37:06.004 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1610.004206}
2020-08-25 03:37:11.003 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1615.0032498}
2020-08-25 03:37:16.005 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1620.0056292}
2020-08-25 03:37:21.001 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1625.0011002}
2020-08-25 03:37:26.007 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1630.0073155}
2020-08-25 03:37:31.008 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1635.0086481}
2020-08-25 03:37:32.687 INFO    Scripting: event:type=test,initiator=Abe Lincoln,place=Washinton,
2020-08-25 03:37:21.001 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1625.0011002}
2020-08-25 03:37:26.007 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1630.0073155}
2020-08-25 03:37:31.008 INFO    Panda HOOK: {"event":"keepalive","time":1635.0086481}
2020-08-25 03:37:34.414 INFO    Scripting: event:type=test2,t=25277.04,type=comment,
```

And here is some code that I have to get the first line `2020-08-25 03:37:32.687 INFO    Scripting: event:type=test,initiator=Abe Lincoln,place=Washinton,`

```
f = open('data.log', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
test2Event = 'event:type=test2'
testEvent = 'event:type=test'
for string in lines:
    if testEvent in string:
        initPerson = string.split('initiator=')[1]
f = open('data.log', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
test2Event = 'event:type=test2'
testEvent = 'event:type=test'
for string in lines:
    if testEvent in string:
        initPerson = string.split('initiator=')[1]
        person = initPerson.split(',')[0]
        print(person)
```

I am getting an error with this code as well as my desired result to this point. I don't understand why, as I have used this exact script with a differnt string to split with no problems.

RESULT

```
Abe Lincoln
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 15, in <module>
    initPerson = string.split('initiator=')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestions on how to get the next line of data so that I can combine the data for insertion into a db or similar would be appreciated...as well as any help with why the error message is happening because I do not see what the issue is.

The code and data is avaiable for testing at https://onlinegdb.com/Hyuuj7Mmv

Comment: The line doesn't contain the string `initiator=` so obviously you can't split on that. What do you hope for that code to actually do?

Comment: I dont understand. In the RESULT above it shows that it did split and got Abe Lincoln as a result and it also threw the error. Ultimately what I am trying to do is get data from the two lines and combine the data together. One line has the name of the person who initiated the event and the other line will have additional data about the event. The main issue I am having is trying to figure out how (if possible) to enter a loop of some kind or similar that will once it hits the event:type=test will look for the very next instance of event:type=test2

Comment: so that I can get both lines and parse the data...and then continue looking for the next instance and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the entire file twice is absolutely excessive.  Instead, keep track of what you have done previously while traversing the file.

```py
seen_test = False   # state variable for keeping track of what you have done
init_person = None  # note snake_case variable convention pro headlessCamelCase

with open('data.log', 'r') as f:
    for lineno, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if 'event:type=test,' in line:
            if seen_test:
                raise ValueError(
                    'line %i: type=test without test2: %s' % (
                        lineno, line))
            init_person = line.split('initiator=')[1].split(',')[0]
            seen_test = True
        elif 'event:type=test2' in line:
            if seen_test:
                # ... do whatever you want with init_person
                # maybe something like
                result = line.rstrip('\n').split(',')
                print('Test by %s got results %s' % (init_person, result[1:]))
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    'line %i: type=test2 without test: %s' % (
                        lineno, line))
            seen_test = False
```

The `enumerate` is just to get a useful line number into the error message when there is a failure; if you are sure that the file is always well-formatted, maybe take that out.

This will still fail if the `type=test` line doesn't contain `initiator=` but we have no idea what would be useful to do in that scenario so I'm not trying to tackle that.

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/OverdueFruitfulComputergames#main.py

Comment: Thanks for responding. This is gonna take me some time to decipher, but just dropping the code in and running it against the data file yielded this error ```File "h:\CODE\pythonScripts\stack.py", line 19
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Sorry, added the missing parenthesis

Comment: Now this error...```NameError: name 'string' is not defined```

Comment: Sorry again, I renamed your variables but forgot the original variable name in one place.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want :

```py
import re

f = open('data.log', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
results = {}
for line in lines:
    if "Scripting:" in line.strip():
        res = dict(re.findall(r"([^= ]+)=(.+?),", line.strip(), re.DOTALL))
        # if the eventtype ends with `2` and match an existing key in results, update data
        if res['event:type'][-1] == '2' and res['event:type'][:-1] in results:
            results[res['event:type'][:-1]].update(res)
        else:
            results[res['event:type']] = res

print(results)

# {'test': {'event:type': 'test2', 'initiator': 'Abe Lincoln', 'place': 'Washinton', 't': '25277.04', 'type': 'comment'}}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. Can you explain what [32:41] is doing?

Comment: It's pulling out a substring at that index.

Comment: [32:41]  retrieve the string that start at position 32 and ends at position 41

Comment: So if the line wasn't exactly like the sample data it would probably have an issue? My intent is to run this against a log file that will have changing data. The basic format will be the same but character lenghts will likely very.

Comment: @XenPanda I updated my answer for your case with `if "Scripting:" in line.strip():`